How to use the Pandas frequency 'C' in gluonts.dataset.common.ListDataset
How can I use the Pandas frequency 'C' in gluonts.dataset.common.ListDataset?
freq = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(calendar=SSEExchangeCalendar())
dd = ListDataset(data, freq=freq)

I'm getting this error:
File "/Users/boss/App/ssm/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gluonts/dataset/common.py", line 252, in ListDataset
  return list(
         ^^^^^   File "/Users/boss/App/ssm/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gluonts/dataset/common.py", line 423, in __call__
  data = t(data)
         ^^^^^^^   File "/Users/boss/App/ssm/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gluonts/dataset/common.py", line 292, in __call__
  raise GluonTSDataError( gluonts.exceptions.GluonTSDataError: Error "CustomBusinessDay cannot be used with Period or PeriodDtype" occurred, when reading field "start"

